# How to access a 'window' of elements from a list in every iteration?

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list [a,b,c,d,e], I want to create a list of tuples [(a,b,c),(b,c,d),(c,d,e)]. Is it possible without using array indices as my loop variable? What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

```
zip(li, li[1:],li[2:])
```

This zips together the elements. Each iteration corresponds to li[i], li[i+1], li[i+2], hence solving the original problem.

Comment: This copies the list over and over, and doesn't work for an iterator / generator rather than list. It also creates all the windows immediately on Python 2, consuming width of window * length of list memory.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this satisfies your constraints, but it should do it.

```
the_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
tuple_size = 3
tuple_list = [tuple(the_list[i-tuple_size:i]) for i in range(tuple_size, len(the_list))]
```

Comment: _without using array indices as my loop variable_ was in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I keep this handy function around for when I want to do this.

```
import itertools

def nwise(it, n, wrapping=False):
    # nwise('ABCD', 2) --> AB BC CD
    # nwise('ABCDEF', 3) --> ABC BCD CDE DEF
    # nwise('ABCD', 2, wrapping=True) --> AB BC CD DA
    # nwise('ABCD', 3, wrapping=True) --> ABC BCD CDA DAB
    copies = itertools.tee(it, n)
    columns = []
    for index, copy in enumerate(copies):
        front = list(itertools.islice(copy, 0, index))
        if wrapping:
            columns.append(itertools.chain(copy, front))
        else:
            columns.append(copy)
    return itertools.izip(*columns)
```